# Define angular material table column definition in a separate component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I see material's [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-wrapped) on this. But I want to go a step further and do something like this:

wrapper-table.html

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-content></ng-content>

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
  </ng-container>
</table>
```

wrapper-table.ts

```js
export class WrapperTable<T> implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(MatHeaderRowDef) headerRowDefs: QueryList<MatHeaderRowDef>;
  @ContentChildren(MatRowDef) rowDefs: QueryList<MatRowDef<T>>;
  @ContentChildren(MatColumnDef) columnDefs: QueryList<MatColumnDef>;
  @ContentChild(MatNoDataRow) noDataRow: MatNoDataRow;

  @ViewChild(MatTable, {static: true}) table: MatTable<T>;

  @Input() columns: string[];

  @Input() dataSource: DataSource<T>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.columnDefs.forEach(columnDef => this.table.addColumnDef(columnDef));
    this.rowDefs.forEach(rowDef => this.table.addRowDef(rowDef));
    this.headerRowDefs.forEach(headerRowDef => this.table.addHeaderRowDef(headerRowDef));
    this.table.setNoDataRow(this.noDataRow);
  }
}
```

my-component.html

```html
<wrapper-table [dataSource]="dataSource" [columns]="displayedColumns" matSort #sort="matSort">
  <!-- Custom column definition to be provided to the wrapper table. -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ADD -->
  <my-custom-columns></my-custom-columns>

  <!-- Custom row definitions to be provided to the wrapper table. -->
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

  <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data that will be provided to the wrapper table. -->
  <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No data</td>
  </tr>
</wrapper-table>
```

my-custom-columns.html

```html
  <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">#{{ row.id | number }}</td>
  </ng-container>
```

So I want to have a common table definition and create different components that will reuse that table definition while having some column definitions in a different component.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I've had the same issue and found the following solution. A custom column, which should be exluded into a separated component, could look like this:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Other columns are placed here -->

  <!-- Custom Column -->
  <custom-column prop="currency" />

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

The part `prop="currency"` is equivalent to the `matColumnDef="currency"` of the default material column.

The component itself looks like this:

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatTableModule, CommonModule],
  selector: 'custom-column',
  template: `
    <ng-container matColumnDef>
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <span> {{ label ?? (prop | titlecase) }}</span>
      </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{ row[prop] }}</td>
    </ng-container>
  `,
})
export class CustomColumnComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  @Input() prop = '';
  @Input() label: string | undefined;

  constructor(@Optional() public table: MatTable<unknown>) {}

  @HostBinding('attr.ariaHidden') ariaHidden!: true;
  @HostBinding('class') classes!: 'column-template cdk-visually-hidden';

  @ViewChild(MatColumnDef, { static: true }) columnDef!: MatColumnDef;
  @ViewChild(MatCellDef, { static: true }) cellDef!: MatCellDef;
  @ViewChild(MatHeaderCellDef, { static: true })
  headerCellDef!: MatHeaderCellDef;
  @ViewChild(MatFooterCellDef, { static: true })
  footerCellDef!: MatFooterCellDef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.table && this.columnDef) {
      this.columnDef.name = this.prop;
      this.columnDef.cell = this.cellDef;
      this.columnDef.headerCell = this.headerCellDef;
      this.columnDef.footerCell = this.footerCellDef;
      this.table.addColumnDef(this.columnDef);
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.table) {
      this.table.removeColumnDef(this.columnDef);
    }
  }
}
```

**Example in StackBlitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-column-component

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Philipp Kief](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6942210/philipp-kief) I have managed to create custom selection column for `CdkTable` (just replacing `Mat` with `Cdk`) like this:

Template:

```
<ng-container cdkColumnDef stickyEnd>
    <th
      *cdkHeaderCellDef
      cdk-header-cell
      class="table-header"
      [class.clickable]="model | smHasValue"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); model.clear()"
      (keydown.Enter)="model.clear()"
    >
      <app-icon
        aria-label="clear selection"
        icon="cross"
        role="button"
        [attr.aria-disabled]="!(model | smHasValue)"
        [style.opacity]="(model | smHasValue) ? 1 : 0"
      />
    </th>

    <td
      *cdkCellDef="let row; let index = index"
      cdk-cell
      class="clickable table-cell"
      [class.selected]="model | isInSelection: row"
      (click)="model.toggle(row)"
    >
      <sz-checkbox
        role="checkbox"
        [attr.aria-label]="'row-' + index"
        [attr.aria-checked]="model | isInSelection: row"
        [checked]="model | isInSelection: row"
      />
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Class:

```
import {SelectionModel} from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import {
  CdkCellDef,
  CdkColumnDef,
  CdkFooterCellDef,
  CdkHeaderCellDef,
  CdkTable,
} from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  Component,
  Input,
  OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  inject,
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-selection-column',
  templateUrl: './selection-column.component.html',
  styleUrl: './selection-column.component.scss',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class SelectionColumnComponent<T> implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() public model!: SelectionModel<T>;

  private table = inject(CdkTable<T>, {optional: true});
  @ViewChild(CdkColumnDef, {static: true})
  private columnDef!: CdkColumnDef;
  @ViewChild(CdkCellDef, {static: true})
  private cellDef!: CdkCellDef;
  @ViewChild(CdkHeaderCellDef, {static: true})
  private headerCellDef!: CdkHeaderCellDef;
  @ViewChild(CdkFooterCellDef, {static: true})
  private footerCellDef!: CdkFooterCellDef;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.table || !this.columnDef) return;

    this.columnDef.name = 'select';
    this.columnDef.cell = this.cellDef;
    this.columnDef.headerCell = this.headerCellDef;
    this.columnDef.footerCell = this.footerCellDef;
    this.table.addColumnDef(this.columnDef);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.table) this.table.removeColumnDef(this.columnDef);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to set `ViewEncapsulation.None` for your table container component to leak styles into here (or just write them again for this column component (which is less flexible)) and add `select` key into `columns` at `*cdkHeaderRowDef="columns"`.

Much thanks.